# Convert array/list to a binary number, based on value of list element: 0 or not 0

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, boolean, converters

I receive an array/list of 4 numbers. First I want to convert this to an array of binaries, which is then converted to a decimal. (I learned, this is possible with the "aggregate" function.)
The binary values are used to assign true/false values to 4 variables based on the position in the array.
If the value of the element of the list = 0 then binary value = 0 = false, if the value <> 0 then the binary value =1 = true.

All 4 numbers are always positive. E.g.

{40 60 80 100} --> {1 1 1 1} --> 15(decimal)
  --> position1 = True; position2 = True; position3 = True; position4 = True;

{20 0 40 80}   --> {1 0 1 1} --> 11(decimal)
  --> position1 = True; position2 = False; position3 = True; position4 = True;

{0 0 20 50}    --> {0 0 1 1} --> 3(decimal)
  --> position1 = False; position2 = False; position3 = True; position4 = True;

Thanks!

Solution I used:

```
double [] source = new double[] {10,20,0,10};
int result = source.Aggregate(0, (a, x) => (a << 1) | (x == 0 ? 0 : 1));

var bools = new BitArray(new int[] { result }).Cast<bool>().ToArray();

position 1 = bools[0]; //true
position 2 = bools[1]; //true
position 3 = bools[2]; //false
position 4 = bools[3]; //true
```

//edited 16/09: added to the request and made it more specific
//2nd edit: added solution I used.

Comment: Made it more specific. And found and added the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `Aggregate` the `int[]` or `List<int>` via *Linq*:

```
  int[] source = new int[] { 20, 0, 40, 80 };

  int result = source.Aggregate(0, (a, x) => (a << 1) | (x == 0 ? 0 : 1));
```

Test:

```
  // "1011 or 11 (decimal)"
  Console.Write(String.Format("{0} or {1} (decimal)",
    Convert.ToString(result, 2), result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to build actual bits representation first and then convert it to decimal:

```
var bitsString = string.Join(string.Empty, list.Select(x => x == 0 ? 0 : 1));
var result = Convert.ToInt32(bitsString, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in a very simple and easy to understand way:

```
var inputCollection = new List<int> { 40, 60, 80, 100 };
var binaryStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var input in inputCollection)
{
    binaryStringBuilder.Append(input == default(int) ? 0 : 1);
}

var binaryRepresentation = binaryStringBuilder.ToString();
var decimalRepresentation = Convert.ToInt32(binaryRepresentation, 2).ToString();
Console.WriteLine("Binary representation: {0}", binaryRepresentation);
Console.WriteLine("Decimal representation: {0}", decimalRepresentation);
```